# roman numbering for few sections

Tags: sectioning, numbering, roman-numerals

I have some attachments in my document and I would like to number them with a roman style.

How can I do this?

I tried:

```
  \documentclass[12pt,a4paper,oneside]{book}
  \begin{document}

  \chapter*{Atachments}
  \renewcommand{\thesection}{\Roman{section}}
  \section{my section}

  \end{document}
```

EDIT
Before the chapter* of attachments, I have an appendix with sections A.1, A.2, A.3.

So, the number of the first section of attachments is IV instead of I.

How can I correct this?

Comment: You have a missing brace at the end - `{\Roman{section}}` works.

Comment: Does adding the missing brace after `\Roman{section}` help?

Comment: @egreg Ops for the last brace. Anyway, I still have a problem. See my edit please.

Comment: @FordPrefect The command `\chapter*` doesn't reset `section`; add also `\setcounter{section}{0}`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `\setcounter{section}{0}`:

```
  \documentclass[12pt,a4paper,oneside]{book}
  \begin{document}
  \appendix
  \chapter{One}
  \section{one}  
  \chapter*{Attachments}
  \setcounter{section}{0}
  \renewcommand{\thesection}{\Roman{section}}  
  \section{my section}
  %
  \end{document}
```

[image]